# Private ssh key content as CLI argument

Tags: bash, ssh, rsa, buildkite

Following the example in Buildkite [charts](https://github.com/buildkite/charts/tree/master/charts/buildkite#installing-the-chart), I'm looking to specify the contents of my private key using `cat`:

```
helm install buildkite --name bk-agent --namespace buildkite \
  --set privateSshKey="$(cat buildkite.key)"
```

The problem I'm having is that `$(cat buildkite.key)` gives an invalid  format where there are no longer newlines. In other words my env variable looks like:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_RSA_KEY=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- abcedefw123232= -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

instead of:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_RSA_KEY=-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
abcedefw123232=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm generating the private key with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -C "my_name" -f ./my_key
```

How can I pass the contents of a private key in the command line?

Comment: What shell are you using? I would expect normal /bin/bash shell to properly populate the argument with newlines when using the `"$(cat buildkite.key)"` syntax. Is it possible that buildkite is the component stripping out the newlines?

Comment: I'm using /bin/bash. I don't think it's the buildkite component.